# JavaScript : detecting resource loading failure (not 404)

Tags: javascript, network-programming

Is there a way to detect resource loading failure that is not a 404 in JS?

```
<html><body>
<img>
<script>

window.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
  console.log(e);
}, true);

document.querySelector("img").src = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";

</script></body></html>
```

I get similar Event objects with no detailed information both for 404 and by turning off wifi. Is there a way to differentiate between these two cases? I'd like to regard 404 as an okay but handle network (socket) failure as an error.

Comment: Can you check `e.message` once?

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala I did and it doesn't have it. According to [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) it won't be an `ErrorEvent` object but an ordinary `Event` object.

Answer (score 0):

The event you get won't tell you that, no. But there are various APIs that help you figure out what's going on. You can check the [`navigator.onLine` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine), but beware that it tells you subtly different things in different brands of browser. (You can also listen for online/offline changes via the [`online`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.ononline) and [`offline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.onoffline) events on `window`.)

Using `navigator.onLine`:

```
window.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
    if (navigator.onLine) {
        // It was probably a 404 or some other problem with this specific image
    } else {
        // User is "offline," according to the browser's rules for what's online and offline
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it might be useful, but I want to handle not only offline but also poor network / socket error.

Comment: @KJ - I don't think you're going to get that level of information. I mean, you could monitor the events above and keep track of how often the state changes between online and offline, which lets you infer a spotty connection, but you're not going to get any level of detail. Even [web sockets](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-sockets.html#network) largely just say something worked or didn't, see [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-sockets.html#feedback-from-the-protocol) and scroll down to the big red-on-yellow warning. (I guess they didn't want us to miss it. :-) )

Answer (score 0):

There are some old fashioned ways to detect whether the loading of images and script files are successful.

With img elements, you can add the onerror event handler either inline or attach postmodern.

With JavaScript files, if there is a function defined, the function will be in the global namespace. For example, test.js:

```
testfunc=function(){

}
```

Then you include the JavaScript file not knowing if it's loaded or not:

```
&lt;script src="test.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
```

But you can interrogate the flag:

```
if (!self.testfunc) // test.js failed to load
```